# How to replace numbers within a array in php

Tags: php

Can you please help me to search the array for decimal numbers or part of it like `". "`(dot and space after it) and replace it with zeros or remove the dot?

Below is part of an array:

```
Array ( [2] => AUD,ADF,1,06-01-2001,3.,3.9532
        [3] => AUD,ADP,1,06-02-2001,99.8222,99.6682
        [4] => AUD,AED,1,06-01-2001,1.8687,1.8664
        [5] => AUD,AFA,1,06-01-2001,2416.57,2413.95
        [6] => AUD,AFN,1,06-01-2001,2416.57,2413.95
        [7] => AUD,ALL,1,06-01-2001,77.,75.9759
        [8] => AUD,AMD,1,06-03-2001,NULL,NULL
        [9] => AUD,ANG,1,06-01-2001,0.9056,0.9046
        [10] => AUD,AOA,1,06-01-2001,3.0751,2.9961
        [11] =>
```

Please look at `[7]` there is number like `77`. or at `[2]` there is `3`. 
(there is nothing after the dot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$array = array(
    'AUD,ADF,1,06-01-2001,3.,3.9532',
    'AUD,ADP,1,06-02-2001,99.8222,99.6682',
    'AUD,ALL,1,06-01-2001,77.,75.9759',
    'AUD,ALL,1,06-01-2001,78.   ,75.9759'
);
//                         ----RegEx Pattern---  Replace   Input
//                         \/       \/       \/    \/       \/
$new_array = preg_replace('/(\d+)\.(\s*)(?!\d)/', '$1', $array);
//                           ^^^ ^^ ^^^^ ^^^^
//                            |   |   |    | 
// Match any digits [0-9] <---|   |   |    |
//         Match a point  <-------|   |    |
// Match spaces and make it optional<--    |
//                                         |
// Lookahead, which means that if there <--|
// is no digits after:                  <--|
// digit[point][0 or several spaces]    <--|
// The whole thing won't be matched.    <--|

// Addition: the first (\d+) is the first match group
// That's why we used $1 in replace !

// \d -> [0-9]
// \s -> space
// \. -> points have to be escaped
// (?!) -> Lookbehind (check : http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)
// * -> Occurs 0 time or plus
// + -> occurs 1 time or plus
// The '/' at the begin and the end are delimiters

print_r($new_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AUD,ADF,1,06-01-2001,3,3.9532
    [1] => AUD,ADP,1,06-02-2001,99.8222,99.6682
    [2] => AUD,ALL,1,06-01-2001,77,75.9759
    [3] => AUD,ALL,1,06-01-2001,78,75.9759
)
```

---

**EDIT:** To answer the question that's in the comment below:

Regular Expressions is all about **regular patterns**. From the desired output, I can see that you want to put everything in quotes except numbers (integer and double/float), we also have dates to put between quotes.
So here's a way to do it:

```
$new_array = preg_replace('/(\d+)\.(\s*)(?!\d)/', '$1', $array); // remove some dots & spaces
$new_array_2 = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]+|\d+-\d+-\d+)/', '\'$1\'', $new_array);
//            Match letters <--^-^-^-^-^  ^-^-^-^-^---> Match digits-digits-digits (for the date part), I don't want to use a LOOOONG RegEx to check if it's valid ...

print_r($new_array); // First replacement
print_r($new_array_2); // Second replacement
```

There is another more reliable way to do this, by using some PHP-Fu:

```
$new_array = preg_replace('/(\d+)\.(\s*)(?!\d)/', '$1', $array); // remove some dots & spaces
// For this code YOU NEED PHP 5.3+ since it's using anonymous functions
$new_array_2 = array_map(function($val){
    $pieces = explode(',', $val);
    $pieces2 = array_map(function($val2){
        if(preg_match('/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/', $val2)){
            return $val2;
        }else{
            return "'$val2'";
        }
    }, $pieces);
    return(implode(',',$pieces2));
}, $new_array);

print_r($new_array);
print_r($new_array_2);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AUD,ADF,1,06-01-2001,3,3.9532
    [1] => AUD,ADP,1,06-02-2001,99.8222,99.6682
    [2] => AUD,ALL,1,06-01-2001,77,75.9759
    [3] => AUD,ALL,1,06-01-2001,78,75.9759
)
Array
(
    [0] => 'AUD','ADF',1,'06-01-2001',3,3.9532
    [1] => 'AUD','ADP',1,'06-02-2001',99.8222,99.6682
    [2] => 'AUD','ALL',1,'06-01-2001',77,75.9759
    [3] => 'AUD','ALL',1,'06-01-2001',78,75.9759
)
```

Comment: OP asked to remove spaces too.

Comment: Thank you, i used the preg_replace and it worked great. can you please explain how did you knew what to write within the function ? or can you direct me to some link that i can learn. (because it worked but i would like to understand how you did it).

Comment: Thia is a great - thank you! 
should i use preg_replace also if i will like to modify the array by adding '' to some of the columns (first, second and fourth)? for example
before:
Array
(
    [0] => AUD,ADF,1,06-01-2001,3,3.9532
    [1] => AUD,ADP,1,06-02-2001,99.8222,99.6682
)

after:

Array
(
    [0] => 'AUD','ADF',1,'06-01-2001',3,3.9532
    [1] => 'AUD','ADP'1,'06-02-2001',99.8222,99.6682
)

Comment: I used: $new_array_2 = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]+|\d+-\d+-\d+)/', '\'$1\'', $new_array); but there is a situation that the if  array will look like : 
Array ( [2] => AUD,ADF,1,06-01-2001,3.,3.9532
        [3] => AUD,ADP,1,06-02-2001,99.8222,99.6682
        [4] => AUD,AED,1,06-01-2001,1.8687,1.8664
        [5] => AUD,AFA,1,06-01-2001,2416.57,2413.95
and if i use: $new_array_2 = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]+|\d+-\d+-\d+)/', '\'$1\'', $new_array); it will also add the ' ' and the NULL value like this 'NULL' when i wanted to do it only for the first,second and the date

Comment: @Leon83 It's getting rather "messy", if there are so many modifications or versions of "array" then just stick to the explode() method and do a loop.

Comment: i fixed it by removing the a-z from the [a-zA-Z] from the prag_replace and changing the NULL in the array to null (from db side null = NULL)

Answer (score 1):

You could use intval() to transform your floating points into integers: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php
Looks like you might have to split the values (separated by commas), transform them and then join them again...

Comment: That's how I understand the question though

Comment: I see what you mean my bad. Preg_replace is what you want then

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), you can pass complete array as input  :

> $j =
>   array('AUD,ADF,1,06-01-2001,3.,3.9532','AUD,ADP,1,06-02-2001,99.8222,99.6682','AUD,AED,1,06-01-2001,1.8687,1.8664','AUD,AFA,1,06-01-2001,2416.57,2413.95','AUD,AFN,1,06-01-2001,2416.57,2413.95','AUD,ALL,1,06-01-2001,77.,75.9759','AUD,AMD,1,06-03-2001,NULL,NULL','AUD,ANG,1,06-01-2001,0.9056,0.9046','AUD,AOA,1,06-01-2001,3.0751,2.9961');
>
> $j = str_replace(".,", "," , $j);
>
> print_r($j);

*Output*

```
Array
 (
[0] => AUD,ADF,1,06-01-2001,3,3.9532
[1] => AUD,ADP,1,06-02-2001,99.8222,99.6682
[2] => AUD,AED,1,06-01-2001,1.8687,1.8664
[3] => AUD,AFA,1,06-01-2001,2416.57,2413.95
[4] => AUD,AFN,1,06-01-2001,2416.57,2413.95
[5] => AUD,ALL,1,06-01-2001,77,75.9759
[6] => AUD,AMD,1,06-03-2001,NULL,NULL
[7] => AUD,ANG,1,06-01-2001,0.9056,0.9046
[8] => AUD,AOA,1,06-01-2001,3.0751,2.9961
)
```

Comment: what about a dot at the end of line?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array_walk() and preg_replace() to do that. Expression for regex should be something like (.)[,\s]